# What type of bulb is globe-shaped with coils inside?

Tags: lighting, bulb, cfl

The bulb looks like a CFL, but looks like the spiral making up the CFL doesn't actually light.

[image]

It takes **AGES** to light up, at first I thought it was broke, but after awhile realized that the bulb just takes 10 minutes to fully turn on. Full disclosure: Just moved into an apt building, and am curious what type of bulb, CFL, or whatever this is, because I've never seen a bulb like it.

Answer (score 7):

It's a CFL globe, but it's either a very old (early prototype) model that warms up slowly or it's simply worn out.

Also, according to [DoxyLover](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/12043/doxylover)...

> ...the glow is starting at the ends of the fluorescent tubing (which
>   are near the base). This causes the part of the tube near the top to
>   cast a shadow on the globe. This is why [it may appear that] the spiral tube
>   is not the light source.